# Template class specialization in seperate .cpp file

Tags: c++, class, templates, specialization

I have the following template class specializations in `foo.h`:

```cpp
using VisionMethod = enum
{
    TemplateMatching,
    ...
};

template <VisionMethod>
class Foo
{
    Foo() = delete;
};

template <>
class Foo<TemplateMatching>
{
public:
    static void get_pose();
};
```

and wish to implement it in `foo.cpp` as:

```cpp
#include "foo.h"

void
Foo<TemplateMatching>::get_pose()
{
    std::cout << "Using foo<TemplateMatching>::get_pose()...\n";
}
```

But I (somewhat understandably) get a linker error when I try to call `foo<TemplateMatching>::get_pose()` in e.g. `main.cpp` after only including `foo.h`. Can I achieve what I want, without having to include `foo.cpp` in either `foo.h` or `main.cpp` - maybe using explicit instantiation? Or is something like `foo.txx` my only "clean" solution?

Comment: No, you cannot. How the compiler would know the implementation of `get_pose()` if it's not included in any of translation units that you're compiling and linking together?

Comment: I figured I could do something similar to explicit instantiation, but guess that doesn't work.

Comment: @Androvich what you describe should works though https://wandbox.org/permlink/LDpxhgeYPkakWFwE

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your specialized function (i.e what you put in `foo.cpp`) in `foo.h` in order to use it in `main.cpp`

There's no escaping this rule as far as I know. But if you want to separate you headers and implementation in order to make your project cleaner, a quite usual solution is to put the implementation in a separate file (to which I usually give the extension .inl) and include it at the end of the header file.
This way, it looks like a header/impl separation from a humain point of view but the compiler still gets to have everything in its header file. This file is **not** a compile target, thus you have not to give it the .cpp extension.

Comment: I'm trying to find a method in which I can separate the implementation from the header despite using templates.

Answer (score 1):

what you proposed already works (after add `#include <iostream>`), you probably forget to tell the compiler to include `foo.cpp`.

like `g++ main.cpp foo.cpp`

https://wandbox.org/permlink/LDpxhgeYPkakWFwE

Comment: Hmm, I'm using CMake and adding the foo.cpp as a source to a library, then linking main with the library.

Comment: @Androvich well it probably something wrong with your CMake config then. I'd suggest post a new question with [mcve] and specify you're asking for help about cmake.

Comment: Okay, I will try to do so. It's just a huge project, so it's a bit difficult to re-create.